# Conditional Display of Rows Using Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba

**UPDATE**

I've modified my code to this but now rows 11 and 12 aren't hiding and unhiding as they should.  Any help?

```
Sub ConditionalDisplay()
    With Worksheets("Data Entry")
    If .Range("C6") = "" Then
        .Rows("7:8").Hidden = True
    Else
        .Rows("7").Hidden = .Range("C6") = "lbs/gal"
        .Rows("8").Hidden = .Range("C6") = "g/L"
    End If
    If .Range("C10") = "" Then
        .Rows("11:12").Hidden = True
    Else
        .Rows("11").Hidden = .Range("C10") = "lbs/gal"
        .Rows("12").Hidden = .Range("C11") = "g/L"
    End If
    End With
End Sub
```

I've had a similar question to this in the past but I'm stumped.  Full disclaimer: I'm a complete beginner when it comes to VBA.

In the below image, I'm trying to have rows 7 and 8 conditionally display based on the input in cell C6.  Additionally, I'm trying to have rows 11 and 12 conditionally display based on input into cell C10.  The data validation choices in cells C6 and C10 are "g/L" and "lbs/gal".

[image]

Here's the code that I've started to write, but it doesn't function as intended.  I have a workbook open event that automatically calls the ConditionalDisplay sub routine when the workbook is opened, but I'm having a hard time figuring out how to unhide rows 7 and 8 after making a selection in cell C6.

```
Sub ConditionalDisplay()
    With Worksheets("Data Entry")
    If .Range("C6") = "" Then
        .Rows("7:8").Hidden = True
    If .Range("C6") = "g/L" Then
        .Rows("8").Hidden = True
    If .Range("C6") = "lbs/gal" Then
        .Rows("7").Hidden = True
      End If
      End If
      End If
    End With
End Sub
```

As written, this code is not working as intended.  Any suggestions?

Comment: Wouldn't it be simpler to ask for VOC content and then ask user to select unit for that number?

Comment: Sounds like you might want to use the `Worksheet_Change` event to run your code

Comment: @LLia: I suppose that's one to go about it, sure =D

Answer (score 1):

What you probably want is:

```
Sub ConditionalDisplay()
    With Worksheets("Data Entry")
        If .Range("C6") = "" Then
            .Rows("7:8").Hidden = True
        End If
        If .Range("C6") = "g/L" Then
            .Rows("8").Hidden = True
        End If
        If .Range("C6") = "lbs/gal" Then
            .Rows("7").Hidden = True
        End If
    End With
End Sub
```

Properly indenting your code helps to see what happens with it. [This](http://rubberduckvba.com/Indentation) can help

Answer (score 0):

Apparently the answer was needing to have the following code on the Data Entry worksheet:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
If Not Intersect(Target, Range("C13")) Is Nothing Then
    ConditionalDisplay
End If
If Not Intersect(Target, Range("C17")) Is Nothing Then
    ConditionalDisplay
End If
End Sub
```

My question is: what exactly do these commands do?  I haven't seen these before.

Comment: Does anyone have any tips on here on what this code is doing?